# Pattern matching in rust and mutability

Tags: rust, pattern-matching, ref

Let's say that I have an `Option<String>` and want to pattern match to get a mutable reference to the `String`. I can do the following (`_a` needs to be mutable):

```rust
  let mut _a: Option<String> = Some(String::from("foo"));
  if let Some(ref mut aa) = _a {
    aa.push_str("_");
    println!("aa: {:?}", aa)
  }
```

Now let's say that I have two `Option<String>` values that I want to pattern match over.

```rust
  let _b: Option<String> = Some(String::from("bar"));
  let _c: Option<String> = Some(String::from("baz"));
  if let (Some(ref mut bb), Some(ref mut cc)) = (_b, _c) {
    bb.push_str("_");
    cc.push_str("_");
    println!("bb: {:?}, cc: {:?}", bb, cc);
  }
```

Strangely, I can use `ref mut` in the patterns, even though neither `_b` nor `_c` are mutable, and I can mutate the strings.  Why is that allowed here in this case? I'd expect this not to compile unless both `_b` and `_c` are declared as mutable similar to the first example above.

I think what may be happening is that a tuple is constructed in the pattern match, i.e. `(_b, _c)`, and then some compiler magic allows the `ref mut` on the pattern that is "bound" to this tuple. Is that correct?

Rust version:

```
rustc 1.41.1 (f3e1a954d 2020-02-24)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mut` isn't necessary if the value is wrapped in a tuple, because the tuple is a new value ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e8a0530370cb49aed1b1d33bdeb46197)):

```
let a = Some(String::from("foo"));
if let (Some(mut aa),) = (a,) {
    aa.push_str("_");
    println!("aa: {:?}", aa)
}
```